# Angular Dynamic URL in lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards, angular-dynamic-components, angular-seo

I have page which renders content based on the params in the url, current route samples are given as follows,

```
domain.com/page/:pageId (domain.com/page/123456) renders Home Page
domain.com/page/:pageId (domain.com/page/567890) renders Offers Page
domain.com/page/:pageId (domain.com/page/987654) renders Blog Page
```

Now i want to implement SEO in my site , so my url will be..

```
domain.com/home renders Home Page
domain.com/offers (domain.com/page/567890) renders Offers Page
domain.com/blog (domain.com/page/987654) renders Blog Page
```

These pages come dynamically form server.

My Dynamic Route looks like,

```
 [  {"path": "home",
        "data": {
                "tile": "Landing Page",
                "pageId":"123456" 
        }
    },
    {"path": "offers",
        "data": {
                "tile": "Offers Page",
                "pageId":"567890" 
        }
    },
    {"path": "Bread",
        "data": {
                "tile": "Blog Page",
                "pageId":"987654" 
        }
    }

]
```

I have pushed my routes as

```
dynamicRoutes.forEach(route => {
    this.router.resetConfig([route, ...this.router.config]);
});
```

But the routes are not navigating and gives 404 error.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Your forEach keeps overwriting. I’d expect only the last dynamicRoute to actually work. this.router.resetConfig([…dynamicRoutes, ...this.router.config]);

Comment: Yes. But event in that case last route should work but it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [redirectTo](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#redirectTo) feature?

e.g.

```js
[  {"path": "home",
       "data": {
                "tile": "Landing Page",
                "pageId":"123456" 
        },
       "redirectTo: '/page/123456'
    },
    {"path": "offers",
        "data": {
                "tile": "Offers Page",
                "pageId":"567890" 
        },
       "redirectTo: '/page/567890'
    },
    {"path": "Bread",
        "data": {
                "tile": "Blog Page",
                "pageId":"987654" 
        },
       "redirectTo: '/page/987654'
    }

]
```

Comment: Robert, Tom wants to implement SEO on his current dynamic site. So "redirectTo: '/page/123456' code again it will redirect to dynamic page. He wants url should be like this domain.com/home.

Comment: Yes , if i use redirectTO it will change the url